# CRM 2011 Hide Picklist Items

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, picklist

I have an old CRM 2011 instance I am working with and on one of the forms I have a picklist dropdown that I need to hide some values in there from the display.  This is not dependent upon anything else, I just don't need them anymore and I don't want to delete them from the list completely.  I found this code online and I have tried to use it but it doesn't work:

Xrm.Page.getControl("field_name").removeOption(1);

I have 13 values I want to hide so I put this in an existing form onload javascript and for RemoveOption(), I grabbed the value of the item I want to hide from the picklist.  This is not working and I am not sure what I am missing.  Do I need to do something proper to calling this script so that the picklist is picked up?

Thanks.

Comment: The code seems ok. Got any errors in the browser console?

Comment: None that I see.

Comment: Check the events and check if the function is fired. You can `alert` something to make sure this part of code is reached.

Comment: So, I am really new to CRM and especially the old 2011 version as I inherited it.  I definitely see the events but how do I determine if the event was fired and how do I set an alert?

Comment: Ok, crm 2011 form events work the same way as in the next versions of crm. Add your js to Form Libraries, add new event (Control: Form, Event: OnLoad) in Event Handlers. In Handler Properties in the Library field chose you js, in the Function field - function which you want to call. In this function you can write `alert(1);` for example to check if your function is fired.